# Drawing a picture of Nodes and where they're pointing to

Tags: java, pointers

I'm supposed to explain visually how four Nodes appear after typing the following code:

```
public class Node
{

    //These two lines are provided
    public Object Data = null;
    public Node Next = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Node a = new Node();
        Node b = new Node();
        Node c = new Node();
        Node d = new Node();

        //These four lines must be used
        b = a.Next;
        //c = b.Next;                //Gives NullPointer error
        //b.Data = c.Next.Data;      //Gives NullPointer error
        c.Next = a;
    }
}
```

From what I've worked on so far, it seems that:

- A points to a Node (unchanged)
- B turns into a null object
- C's Node points to A
- D points to a Node (unchanged)

([image: This is the image] This is the image that I'm referring to from my debugger)

Is it normal for the two lines above to give NullPointer errors? Also are my guesses kinda close to the picture? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `Data` and `Next` of each `Node` Object is null, let's look at it in a step by step walkthrough starting from your main function. (it is recommended you use camelCase for those variable names https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

```
Node A = new Node(); 
Node B = new Node(); 
Node C = new Node(); 
Node D = new Node(); // Defines non-null A, B, C, and D Nodes

B = A.Next; // B = null; because the Next and Data of each node is null

C = B.Next; // C = (a non existent) b.next causing a null pointer error
B.Data = C.Next.Data; // c.next == null. null.Data doesn't exist. 

C.Next = A; // C.Next = A; A == new Node(); no error
```